# Hibernate OpenSession() Vs GetCurrentSession()

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

I am new to N hibernate. I am using n hibernate in my application. I write code that works successfully but little slow, because when I checked in hibernate profiler it show me some reasons for slow process."More than one session per request" my code is

```
          using (ISession session = NContext._mSessionFactory.OpenSession())
          {
              ICriteria criteriaAspNetUser = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(AspNetUsers));
              criteriaAspNetUser.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("Email", email));
              criteriaAspNetUser.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("PasswordHash", password));
```

When I use GetCurrentSession() function it return some exceptions

> No CurrentSessionContext configured (set the property current_session_context_class)!

but when I add following code in my config file

> "property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static /property>"

it display different exception that is

> no session bound to the current context

I am working on it last 3 days but can't found any solution please help me I am worried about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CurrentSessionContext` only tells NHibernate which implementation of session context it should use. There are multiple available depending on type of application you are writing. Once it is configured, you then need to bind every session object that you create to the session context. Following code explains how to do that

```
public class SessionManager
{
    private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static SessionManager()
    {
        sessionFactory = new DatabaseConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
        {
            return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }

        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        return session;
    }

    public static void Unbind()
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you need a session object, you can call `SessionManager.GetCurrentSession` and it would internally do the following

1. Check if there is an existing session object bound to the context, if yes, return the current session from the session factory because that is the one bound to the context
2. If not, then open a new session, bind it to the `CurrentSessionContext` and return the session object

Notice that there is an `Unbind` method on `SessionManager` that you can use to unbind a session object.

Now, about the warning `more than one session per request`. This warning is clearly telling you that you are using more than one session per request (if you are using it in the context of a web application). A popular approach to counter this warning is to use a "Session per request" pattern. In this pattern, for every incoming request, you create a new session object as the request hits your code, use that session object through out the request processing and dispose the session object when request leaves your code. The following code can be added to `global.asax.cs` file of an ASP.NET MVC application to get "session per request"

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();
        session.Close();
        session.Dispose();
    }
}
```